# modelling wireless networks and mobile nodes

Tags: wireless, omnet++, inet, mobility

I am new to omnet++ and started using it a couple of days ago.
I followed the tic toc example and now, I need to learn how to simulate wireless networks
 I need to implement a very simple example similar to tic toc scenario but with a wireless network and two mobile nodes

should I use INet/Mixim for modeling wireless and/or mobility?
or there is another simpler way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you need to use INET for including mobility in your modules. There are several examples in INET which would help you in your project.

Comment: What is the difference between INet and mixim?

Comment: mixim is not updated according to latest versions of Omnet++. and they have included mixim examples in INET.

Comment: Not only the examples. Most of the MiXiM code is fully integrated in INET.